# Entity Framework mapping

Tags: entity-framework, .net-3.5

Has anyone a good sample for a "real" mapping scenario with Entity Framework. Not one of that simple Table <-> Entity one ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at the [Defining Advanced Data Models](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738640.aspx) article on MSDN, it has the following subjects:

- [Define a Model with a Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896279.aspx)
- [Define a Model with Modification Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716731.aspx)
- [Define a Model with Complex Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738613.aspx)
- [Define a Model with Table-per-Type Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738685.aspx)
- [Define a Model with Table-per-Hierarchy Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738443.aspx)
- [Define a Model with Multiple Entity Sets per Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738537.aspx)
- [Define a Model with Single Entity Mapped to Two Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896233.aspx)
- [Define a Model with a Horizontal Partition in the Storage Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853328.aspx)